# Создание объекта по имени класса

Tags: c#

Пишу планировщик для разных задач работы с БД, это загрузка, выгрузка, обработка данных. все действия реализуются в виде отдельных классов и наследуются от абстрактного класса и должны реализовывать обязательный метод Run()

Сами задачи хранятся в таблице БД. в одном из полей указывается имя класса метод Run() которого нужно выполнить по расписанию. соответственно при запуске нужно определить экземпляр какого класса создавать

```
private void TimerTask(object Obj)
{
    IsRuning = true;
    SetNextStartTask();

    switch (Metod)
    {
        case "ExportXML0":
            {
                Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    ExportData export = new ExportXML0(Id);
                    export.Run();
                });
                if (task.IsCompleted) { task.Dispose(); }
                break;
            }
        case "ExportUniversalToTXT":
            {
                Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    ExportData export = new ExportUniversalToTXT(Id);
                    export.Run();
                });
                if (task.IsCompleted) { task.Dispose(); }
                break;
            }
    }

    IsRuning = false;
}
```

Сейчас классов относительно не много, около 30. Когда их будет 100+ то этот метод будет выглядеть страшно. Как можно упростить этот выбор?

В некоторых языках, к примеру SQL или Caché Basic можно написать какой-то текст и его выполнить, как красиво это сделать в C#

Comment: Ключевое слово - рефлексия

Answer (score 4):

Используйте рефлексию

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  ExportData export = (ExportData)Activator.CreateInstance(
    assemblyName, Metod, new object[] {Id}
  );
  export.Run();
});
if (task.IsCompleted) { task.Dispose(); }
```

Comment: А что в данном примере есть `id`?

Comment: @NewView это тот же `id`что и у автора вопроса в `ExportData export = new ExportXML0(Id);`

Comment: Ааа, понял, спасибо.